# Xcode Instruments is running slowly and taking too long to respond

Tags: xcode, xcode5, instruments, nszombie, xcode-instruments

My project has a memory problem (**EXC_BAD_ACCESS**) : I want to find what the problem is in my project. I am using Instruments to find the memory problem. However now that I have Xcode 5 on Mountain Lion, it is extremely slow and I have to wait about 5 minutes for a response. Is anyone else having this same problem? I am using iOS simulator too.

Comment: you shouldn't need instruments to find this error. use the debugger and/or NSZombie. Instruments is slow because it does a lot of data collection and analysis.

Comment: @BradAllred how I can use NSZombie without instruments ? Thanks

Comment: you can enable zombies from the menu Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme then the diagnostics tab.

Comment: before I did this and after ı will start my app on similator. right ?  only this steps ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me. you do need to rebuild and relaunch your app after enabling zombies.

Comment: when I rebuild after enabling zombies ,can I start to find where is crashing problem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40393/discussion-between-erhan-demirci-and-brad-allred)